# get string and number from url via regex and htaccess

Tags: regex, .htaccess

im currently loosing sleep over a regex problem. I got over a thousand urls that look like this:

/downloads/category-01/name-of-file-95/

im trying to get "name-of-file" and "95" into two separate variables.

i got this atm:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule downloads/.+/([a-z0-9-\-+])+-([\d]+)/ r.php?t=$1&$2
```

that gives me this output in a htaccess tester:

:80/r.php?t=e&469

the first variable for some reason only gives me the last character from the string i want, the id at the end works.

the endgoal is to get a redirect to a url that looks as:

/resources/name-of-file.95/

help me stackoverflow, you are my only hope :)

thanks!

Comment: Quantify the character class, not the group. `downloads/.+/([a-z0-9-\-+]+)-([\d]+)/`.

Answer (score 0):

Got it!

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule downloads/.+/([a-z0-9/-]+)-([\d]+)/ r.php?t=$1&$2
```

thanks! may this one day save another noble soul